# Java Counting letter,digit and symbol

Tags: java, count

I want to count the number of letter, digit and symbol using JAVA
However the result output is not ideal. it should be 5,2,4
but I got 5,2,13

```
    int charCount = 0;
    int digitCount = 0;
    int symbol = 0;
    char temp;
    String y = "apple66<<<<++++++>>>";
    for (int i = 0; i < y.length(); i++) {
        temp = y.charAt(i);

        if (Character.isLetter(temp)) {
            charCount++;
        } else if (Character.isDigit(temp)) {
            digitCount++;
        } else if (y.contains("<")) {
            symbol++;
        }
    }

          System.out.println(charCount);
          System.out.println( digitCount);
          System.out.println( symbol);
```

Comment: How are you expecting 4 ? There are 13 non numeric non letter symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
    } else if (temp == '<')) {
        symbol++;
    }
```

In your solution, for every non-letter-or-digit character you check if *the entire string contains* `<`. This is always true (at least in your example), so the result you get is the number of special characters in the string.

Comment: He is not checking for every character, but for every character that is not a letter nor a digit.

Answer (score 1):

You should use **y.charAt(i) == '<'** rather than y.contains("<")

if you use y.contains("<"), it uses the whole string to check whether it contains '<' or not. Since String y contains '<'. When in for loop, there are 4 '<', 6 '+' and 3 '>'.

For checking such charraters, y.contains("<") always be true. That is why you get 13 (=4+6+3) for symbol rather than 4.

Answer (score 0):

This bit is wrong:

```
y.contains("<")
```

You are checking the whole string each time when you only want to check a single character (temp)

Answer (score 0):

```
int charCount = 0;
int digitCount = 0;
int symbol = 0;
char temp;
String y = "apple66<<<<++++++>>>";
for (int i = 0; i < y.length(); i++) {
    temp = y.charAt(i);

    if (Character.isLetter(temp)) {
        charCount++;
    } else if (Character.isDigit(temp)) {
        digitCount++;
    ****} else if (temp =="<") {
        symbol++;
    }
}****
```

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (y.contains("<")) {
```

should be

```
else if (temp == '<') {
```

because else every time youu have no letter or digit it is raised.

Answer (score 0):

```
y.contains("<")
```

seaches for the substring `"<"` in the string `"apple66<<<<++++++>>>"` and it always finds it. This happens `13` times which is the number of chars in the substring `<<<<++++++>>>"` which does contains neither a letter nor a digt.